# Unable to get output using AngularJS and MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net mvc and angularjs. I'm stuck with a piece of code where I'm unable to get the output. Can any of you suggest the bug below:

**Here's my code:**  
**i. Module.js**
`var app = angular.module("myApp", []);`    
**ii. Controller.js**

```
app.controller("myCntrlr", function ($scope, angularService) {    
    GetAllEmployee();

    function GetAllEmployee(){
        var getData = angularService.getEmployees();
        getData.then(function (emp) {
            $scope.employees = JSON.parse(emp.data);
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting records');
        });
    }
});
```

**iii. Service.js**

```
app.service("angularService", function ($http) {
    this.getEmployees = function () {
        return $http.get("Home/GetAll");
    };
});
```

**A. HomeController.cs**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        EmployeeDAL objDAL = new EmployeeDAL();
        var employeeList = objDAL.SelectAllData();
        return Json(employeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**A(i). EmployeeDAL.cs** (My DataAccessLayer)

```
public string SelectAllData()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String json = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ToString());
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            json = GetJson(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return json;                
        }
        catch
        {
            return json;
        }
    }

    // Method to convert Datatable to JSON Array
    public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer JSSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<String, Object>> DtRows = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
        Dictionary<String, Object> newRow = null;

        // Code to loop through each row in datatable and add it to the dictionary object
        foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
        {
            newRow = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                newRow.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), drow[col]);
            }
            DtRows.Add(newRow);
        }
        // Serialising the dictionary object to produce json
        return JSSerializer.Serialize(DtRows);
    }<br/>
```

**B. Index.cshtml**

```
@*@model AngularCRUD.Models.Employee*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrlr">
        <table cellpadding="12">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>
                        {{employee.Id}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.Email}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.Age}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Edit | Delete
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I keep getting the below error 
**[ngRepeat:dupes]**
One more query: is there a need to comment out **@model AngularCRUD.Models.Employee** from Index.cshtml?

Comment: are you sure you need asp.net and angular? just some advice but learn them separately first and double check your requirements befor you build an app with both.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is any data in employees array.

And don't use Asp.Net views and angular together. Use one of them.

Comment: Yes, there is data in 'employees'. I'm fetching it from SQL server. I'm also able to convert it to JSON data, but concern is that, data is not rendered on screen. Also would like to know the reason why you suggest using either Angular or ASP.net MVC Views? Can we not display data on view using Angular? Or is there any drawback of doing so?

Comment: You are using an Asp.net view file to display the data. This is ok if you are rendering data in server side. Since you are using Angular to get data, you don't need an Asp.net view file instead use a html file. Therefore it will remove the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For the error `[ngRepeat:dupes]`

Angular disallow duplication

[From angular code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L457)

```
throw ngRepeatMinErr('dupes',
              "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: {0}, Duplicate key: {1}, Duplicate value: {2}",
              expression, trackById, value);
```

So, as the error indicate you need to use `track by`

```
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees track by $index">
```